# Rails won't load asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I ran `rake assets:precompile` by mistake on development, and Rails stopped loading the assets on development. I only get `application.js` and `application.css` loaded.

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

application.css:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

Using Rails 3.2.2

Comment: Could you post your `config/application.rb` and `config/environments/development.rb` files?  That would make it much easier to track down your issue.

Answer (score 7):

Try deleting the compiled assets from your local development environment:

`rm -rf public/assets`

**Edit:**

In addition, make sure to set `config.assets.compress = false` and `config.assets.debug = true` in your `development.rb`.

Comment: @macool can you look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020842/rails-wont-load-asset-pipeline/16209053#16209053) below and see it that works for you?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr

1. `$ rake assets:clean`
2. restart rails server `$ rails server -e development`
3. clear browser cache, or do a `ctrl+shift+r` on the app page

Now everything should be as it was before you ran `rake assets:precompile`

-- end tl;dr --

If the above doesn't work, then a detailed list of steps:

1. Do `$ rake assets:clean` or `$ rm -rf public/assets` to remove the generated assets.
2. In application.rb, ensure:

   - `config.assets.enabled = true` (to enable rails' asset pipleline)
3. In development.rb, ensure:

   - `config.assets.compress = false` (so as to not gzip the assets)
   - `config.assets.debug = true` (so as to not merge all css and js files into application.[cs|js])
   - `config.assets.compile = true` (or not set - to enable runtime compilation of assets)
   - `config.serve_static_assets = false`  (or not set)
4. Finally, restart your rails server `$ rails server -e development`

This should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Running `rake assets:precompile` generates static assets under `public/assets` which causes Rails to serve these directly. To prevent this you can:

1. Manually delete those files or
2. Run `rake assets:clean`

Answer (score 0):

Open `config/application.rb` and set the following:

`config.assets.enabled = true`

Answer (score 0):

If cleaning your asset directory and ensuring your configuration was correct as indicated by the previous answers did not work - is there a possibility that you're using page caching?

If the page was generated with `src` tags pointing to your compiled files, they would need to be regenerated now.

Comment: They weren't generated with `src` tags. It isn't also using page caching, I already tried deleting all cache.

Answer (score 0):

Incase it's helpful to anyone - I had an issue where neither application.js/.css loading in development (I could still see the manifest lines when viewing the source).

I was running an old rails 3.2.2 app for some reason I had to go in and add blank line to both the manifest files (application.js & application.css) and save them - then assets started working properly.

I removed the blank lines and it still worked so I'm assuming perhaps it just needed a newer modified date stamp on the files.