# Asset pipeline precompiled locally with Rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 3.2.9 and I precompiled my asset pipeline locally before the application deploy (with Capistrano) and it works good. I used:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

In "config" directory I only modified `deploy.rb` and `production.rb`. Now, in development mode, when I put new code in `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` I can't see changes in my application.

For example, I use jQuery multiselect in this way:

```
$("#question_number").multiselect({ 
    multiple: false,
    header: false,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "blind",
    minWidth: "200",
    selectedList: 1
});
```

Before precompilation, the select change graphic, but now remain a classic html select. I think that the problem is the precompilation, because I took source code precompilation and a new `jQuery` multiselect works. I tried to do a new precompilation, but nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `rake assets:clean`, clean your browser cache and reload the page. That should solve the problem for you.

Also, look at: [Rails won't load asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020842/rails-wont-load-asset-pipeline/16209053) for more details.

Comment: My first step was remove assets directory and check configuration, but nothing change. I followed your suggestion: now I lost all jQuery theme in my application. I did a new precompilation and I continuous to see all select in html.

Comment: Are you verifying on your developer machine, or another box after deploying with capistrano? Basically, what is the RAILS_ENV where you are observing the problem? If it is development, they try without precompiling your assets.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is on my developer machine. I must do an upgrade to my application and I can't using jQuery now.

Comment: I'm in development mode. If I change my previus code (with no assets pipeline), all works fine. My problem is continue my project (with assets pipeline) because I have my Git file used to deploy.

Comment: It appears that you are compiling assets on your machine and then pushing them on your server using git. While it works, it is not advisable to do so. Why don't you use `Capistrano` to compile assets on your server itself? This way you can get rid of them from git.

Comment: It gave me problem to compile on server. Reading of forum, I understood that It wasn't a problem precompile localy. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Command `rake assets:clean` works good, thanks so much Puneet.

In the future, pay more attention to change nothing into asset pipeline files, such as application.js.

For me, only a change gave problems.

Comment: absolutely. never ever change a generated asset file. ever :)